# Facing some issues while executing javascript using phantomJS driver with serenity

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am facing the following issue, while executing javascript from the PhantomJS Driver using serenity framework.

```
 (PhantomJSDriver) driver).executeScript("document.getElementsById('whereOut')")
```

Error:

> {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'document.getElementsById('whereOut')')","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"69","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:33819","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3
>   (java
>   1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"document.getElementsById(\u0027whereOut\u0027)\",\"args\":[]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b0246730-4435-11e6-b64c-7bf1e13a7577/execute"}}
>       Command duration or timeout: 278 milliseconds

Also tried following code:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('whereOut')")
```

above code returns a null value even if I add a return value as shown below:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.activeElement")
```

Returns a null value.

Has anyone tried to change the `css` of a particular element using phantom js?

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('whereOut').className=''")
```

What I figured out is that while executing above line of code, I don't get the element using `javascript` execution while the same element is retrievable using pure selenium code with firefox browser.

P.S. I am using phantomJS 1.9.7 version along with serenity: 1.0.56.

Comment: But JavascriptExecutor is not implemented by PhantomJSDriver, how could this possibly work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `executeAsyncScript` with `callback` as below :-

```
String changedClassName = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];var element = document.getElementById('whereOut');element.setAttribute('class', 'your new class name');callback(element.getAttribute('class'));");
```

**Edited** :- If you want to modify `className` of desire element then try using `.setAttribute` as below

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("whereOut"));
String changedClassName = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];arguments[0].setAttribute('class', arguments[1]);callback(arguments[0].getAttribute('class'));", element, "your new class name");
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Not working, I get this error [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@4fb0e071 -> unknown locator]

Comment: @BilboBaggins make sure first at your browser console `document.getElementById('whereOut')` returns something or not

Comment: if I do the same using selenium WebElement element = driver.findElementBy(By.id("whereOut")); or driver.findElementBy(By.cssClassName("whereOut")); (method for cssClass name may not be correctly named), I do get the desired div tag, but I can't remove its css using WebElement instance for that I have to execute the above (mentioned in question ) java script which is not working strange because the same thing works fine with pure selenium code, but I have to use the Serenity BDD framework

Comment: @BilboBaggins ok if you want to modify class name you can do this by javascript using `.setAttribute()`..see edited answer..